# changing a textbox value when selected index from a combobox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a combobox that has data fetched from the database. When an index is selected from the combobox, a textbox value then gets a value from the database depending on the index selected from the combobox. I have with the following codes.

```
<form action = '' method = "POST">
  <b> School ID: </b><br />
  <select name = "school_id" required id = "schoold_id" onchange="get_data(this.value)">
  <option value = "" selected></option>
  <?php 
  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT school_id FROM school";
  $result = $db->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              echo "<option value = ".$row["school_id"].">".$row["school_id"]."</option>";
        }
  }
  ?>
  </select><br /><br />
  <b> Batch Number: </b><br />
  <input type= "text" name = "batch_no" /required><br /><br />
  <b> School Name: </b><br />
  <input type= "text" name = "school_name" /readonly><br /><br />
  <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
  </form>
```

The combobox here is the school id and the textbox that needs to be changed is the school name.

I tried using javascript and here it is that I used.

```
<script>
function get_data(value){
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "HTML",
    async: false,
    data: {value: value}
    success: function(data) {
       //here we can populate the required fields based on value from database                
    }
 });
}</script>
```

and this is the ajax file

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$myschoolid = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'school_id'));

$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT school_name FROM main where school_id = ?');
$sql->bind_param('i', $myschoolid);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
if ($result->numrows >0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $newschoolid = $row["school_name"];
    }
    echo $newschoolid;
}
?>
```

I'm probably doing something wrong here. I'm not entirely familiar with ajax. Would appreciate help.

Comment: *"I'm probably doing something wrong here."* - Well `async:false` is almost never a good idea, but anyway...your code is incomplete: you don't do anything in the `success` handler. What is the `while` loop in the ajax.php supposed to do? At the moment it seems to keep overwriting the same variable, so with the `echo` statement after the loop all you're outputting is the last value.

Comment: Remove the faux XML markup, it's just ugly. What should the parser make of `<input ...  /readonly>`?

Comment: my bad the while is supposed to be an if